# CopyfromRecordset in JAVA

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-poi

My requirement is that i have to transfer the data from Result set ( using `JAVA`) to `excel`. I can do that cell by cell.

However in VBA, there is `COPYFROMRECORDSET` method where in i can transfer the entire data in 1 go.

was wondering if `JAVA` has any such method.

please share if anyone knows how can we effectively and quickly transfer the data from `RESULTSET` (in `java`) to`EXCEL` ( for excel i am using `poi`)

Answer (score 0):

In the standard Java libraries there is no such method. But you are not the first who has this task - with a little googling you can find some implementations, for example [this](http://www.codereye.com/2009/09/converting-resultset-to-excel-table-in.html).